# AngularJS : DOM manipulation of ng-repeat elements in a directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angularJS. I am trying to implement the a simple functionality wherein there are a number of checkbox options and one specific function needs to be called on click of these checkbox options something similar to

```
 $(parentDiv).on("click",'input[type="checkbox"]', functionToBeCalled});
```

I am trying to use a directive for this section with content similar to

```
 <div>
    <span ng-repeat="subsection in section"><input type="checkbox"  value="subsection.name"></input> {{subsection.name}} </span>
</div>
```

Directory

```
app.directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'filter.html',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.find("input").bind('click', function() {
        //do some data manipulation
      });
    });
 };
});
```

When i use the link function I find that if I use elem.find('input[type="checkbox"]) gives me an empty object so it is not compiled before that. Kindly let me know how to address this situation. I did a bit of a research and found out about compile function which manipulates DOM before linking,but i am not able to think of the approach ahead. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use **ngClick** or **ngChange** Directive inn angularjs

```
<div>
    <span ng-repeat="subsection in section">
    <input type="checkbox"  value="subsection.name" ng-click="myFunc(subsection.name)" /> {{filter.name}} </span>
</div>
```

here in the example i used ng-click = "myFunc" and pased the value in that function

Comment: The problem is I have ten such sections each of which has more than five checkboxes on click of which the same function gets executed. I did not want to use ng-click on all ten sections.I wanted to know if a generic solution for this case is possible.

Comment: I thnk i am not clear on what I am trying to say. Please refer the below fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uidev_26/cmbj92c1/4/.All I want to do is call the function once instead of calling for each section.

Answer (score 0):

It might help for us to know how you directive looks like and specifically what `element` that directive is attached to, since you're speaking about `elem`.

Nevertheless, if you just need functions to be called when the checkbox is clicked, you can use built-in angular functions for this:

- [ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)
- [ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)

Comment: Added the same. I am using something like <div mydir></div>